# Cant work out why this IF request is returning true

Tags: python

Does anyone know why this IF request in Python is returning true? Here is the code:

```
var1 = 1

if var1 == 100 or 50:
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

I can't work it out because var1 does not equal either 100 or 50.

Comment: If that's how your indentation looks it's not going to work.

Comment: That's obviously not the problem or the user would have gotten a totally different error.  It's clearly a new user that doesn't know how to format code here.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html Operations closer to the top happen ahead of those lower on the list. Hence, var1 == 100 is evaluated first, that result is then or'd with 50 (which is always True). Short circuiting (another topic to look at) will skip the 'or' evaluation if the == result is True.

Answer (score 3):

For the if statement, it reads `if (var1 == 50) or 50`

50 is `True`, so "yes" is printed out.

If you want to see if `var1` is 100 or 50, you can do this:

```
var1 = 1

if var1 == 100 or var1 == 50:
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no
```

Answer (score 2):

This `if var1 == 100 or 50:` is not working the way you think it is.

Using parenthesis it actually looks like this `if(var1 == 100) or 50`.

50 is not zero (zero is inherently `False`, integers that are not zero, positive or negative, are inherently `True`) so it will always evaluate `True`

Use this instead:

`if var1 in (100,50):`

Comment: +1 for the alternative syntax using `in`

Answer (score 0):

I think your semantics is incorrect:

```
if var1 == 100 or var1 == 50:
```

Seems more likely.

Comment: It's the semantics, not the syntax that's incorrect...

Comment: I know.  As described in another answer, it's because of the way it's phrased that it always returns true.  I was correcting the syntaxz he was likely going for so it would actually work.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the *syntax*.

Comment: I agree with @TimPietzcker